# Convert text to table

Tags: regex

I would like convert text into a table. Here is a link to the text

> http://www.tcdb.org/public/tcdb

Short example:

```
>gnl|TC-DB|A0CIB0|1.A.17.3.1 Chromosome undetermined scaffold_19, whole genome shotgun sequence OS=Paramecium tetraurelia GN=GSPATT00007662001 PE=4 SV=1
MDDQNQPILQEQPKPKQKKPLLNTKMVKKQKMQNKKEENLREILNFYTNQVDARKFLQKM
KAVVDSNQQEKKYQDDFLNPNEYNEMQDIYEDYNMGDLVIVFPNPDADGVKNPPITYKEA
PLTKTNFYSKIGNVSYENDIDELCVDEMEYLRNMRNVDGEHMDQDHVKEEI
>gnl|TC-DB|A0CS82|9.B.82.1.5 Chromosome undetermined scaffold_26, whole genome shotgun sequence - Paramecium tetraurelia.
MIIEEQIEEKMIYKAIHRVKVNYQKKIDRYILYKKSRWFFNLLLMLLYAYRIQNIGGFYI
VTYIYCVYQLQLLIDYFTPLGLPPVNLEDEEEDDDQFQNDFSELPTTLSNKNELNDKEFR
PLLRTTSEFKVWQKSVFSVIFAYFCTYIPIWDIPVYWPFLFCYFFVIVGMSIRKYIKHMK
KYGYTILDFTKKK
```

I wanted to have columns for example delimited with pipe `|` or `;`

```
|>gnl|TC-DB|A0CIB0|1.A.17.3.1| Chromosome undetermined scaffold_19, whole genome shotgun sequence OS=Paramecium tetraurelia GN=GSPATT00007662001 PE=4 SV=1|
MDDQNQPILQEQPKPKQKKPLLNTKMVKKQKMQNKKEENLREILNFYTNQVDARKFLQKM
KAVVDSNQQEKKYQDDFLNPNEYNEMQDIYEDYNMGDLVIVFPNPDADGVKNPPITYKEA
PLTKTNFYSKIGNVSYENDIDELCVDEMEYLRNMRNVDGEHMDQDHVKEEI
```

I am working with Windows and I don't know how to do it

I just know

- every row starts with `>`
- I want to substitute the first whitespace in a row with a delimiter like `|` or `;`
- after the first regular expression new line in a row, I want also a delimiter
- everything between the regular expression first new line and `>` should go into a new column (it's a sequence of a protein)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Our formatting works a little different — you'll have to indent code by 4 spaces or press `Ctrl-K`. Can you check your post and see if it's displayed correctly now?

Comment: What OS are you doing this in? That will determine what tools are available.

Comment: Windows, as stated @ebg

Comment: sorry I should have been more clear. Which version of windows?

Answer (score 1):

If I was in your situation, I'd try an editor with Regular Expression support. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297569/free-windows-gui-text-editor-supporting-regular-expressions-for-programmers) has some suggestions for editors as the answers.

You could also use [perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), or another programming language with strong Regular Expression support. You can get a version of perl from [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl), or as part of [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). Cygwin also has editors with Regular Expression support, but for a nice GUI editor you would need to download and configure the X-Server portion of Cygwin and that may be a steep learning curve for you to jump.